# Which value of $c$ makes $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{c}{n!}$ converge to 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the constant $c$ such that this series converges to $1$?
> $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{c}{n!}$$

I tried with $1$, but I don't know if it converges exactly to $1$ cause I noticed that it might converges to $e$.

And I also found $c=\dfrac{1}{e-1}$, but I doubt it converges to $1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c}{n!} = c \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't converge to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c}{n!}=c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
We all are familiar with the exapansion,
$$e^{x}=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\cdots$$
Hence, for $x=1$ we get,
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
But the question states that the lower limit starts from $1$, therefore, modifying the expression a little gives us,
$$e=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
So,
$$e-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
Multiplying by the constant $c$, we get,
$$c\left(e-1\right)=c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$c\left(e-1\right)=S$$
But,
$$S=1$$
$$c\left(e-1\right)=1$$
and finally,
$$c=\frac{1}{e-1}$$

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the required sum is $S := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{c}{n!}$.
Since $c$ is a constant, you have $S = c  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$.
Note the series converges to $e-1$. Therefore, $S = c(e-1)$. Since you want the sum to converge to $1$, use $1=c(e-1)$ which makes $c = \frac{1}{e-1}$.

Edit: People pointed out that the previous answer was not thorough, so I modified it appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: @Aditya thanks!

Comment: @AdityaMorolia  
Much more thorough now.   However, many students will get confused by "Set $c = 1$" and then later "$c= \frac{1}{e-1}$".  Why not retain c as a variable and then solve for c, leaving out $c = 1$ entirely?   I have suggested this also as an edit.